# Undefined class , cannot reach from main to my header

Tags: c++, class, undefined, member

I have a problem,i can not reach my function in the header, i want to call it in my main function but it says that.
Error   2   error C2039: 'Test' : is not a member of 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>'
and undefined class why is this happening?
Note: i erase the not important parts of my codes.

```
 #include "CompressHeader.h"
    int main()
    {     input.get(ch);
         string a=ch;
            if(Test(a))//here is undefined one.
            {
             }
```

my header

```
class Compress
{
public:
    Compress();
   Compress(string hashData[],const int size); //constructor
    void makeEmpty();
    bool Test(string data);//To test if data in the dictionary or not.
```

Comment: Where does `temp2` come from?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: it is come from an ifstream input.get(ch);

Comment: @M.J.Watson `if(Test(a))`  There is no such `Test`.  There is a `Compress::Test`, but that function is not what you're attempting to call in `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Test is member function of Compress, so you need to invoke through an instance of Compress, like:

```
string a=temp2;
Compress c;
if (c.Test(a)) {...}
```

or put this code inside a member function of Compress

Answer (score 2):

Because the method you want to call is not a `static` method, you will need to create an object (an instance) of the class `Compress` to call that method, something like:

```
#include "CompressHeader.h"
int main()
{
    // temp2 is not defined in your example, i made it a string
    string a = "temp2";

    //Create the object
    Compress compressObject;
    //Call the method using the object
    if(compressObject.Test(a) {
    //...
```

Answer (score 1):

In below code:

```
if(Test(a))//here is undefined one.
```

you call a global function `Test` - which is actually a member of `Compress` class.  So to fix your code you should call Test on Compress object:

```
Compress c;
if (c.Test(a)){}
```